# Is it idiomatic to use "easy [way]" to emphasize a tip/method/approach is easy to understand and easy to use, such as "easy tip"?

Tags: word-usage

I used "easy tip" to describe a speech tip ([Is there a rule or convention to make a name, in particular, name a tip? For example, is "Start with Opposite" a clear name?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/238086/95044))

I was trying to emphasize the tip is easy to understand and easy to use.

Is it idiomatic to use "easy [way]" to emphasize a tip/method/approach is easy to understand and easy to use?

Imagine I need to process some photos, I resize them one by one, and then one of friends tell me a tip, which is, use a website to resize them in a batch; another  friend give me another tip, a snippet programming code. Obviously, the former tip is much easier than the latter, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that a tip, in this sense, means a "suggestion". A *suggestion* is just a sentence, not the act the sentence suggests. For example:

> **Wrong:** Here's an easy tip: use a clothespin to hold that while soldering.
>
> **Acceptable:** Here's a tip: use a clothespin to hold that easily while soldering.
>
> **Acceptable:** Here's a tip: an easy way to hold that while soldering is with a clothespin.

The *tip* isn't "easy" (or "difficult"), it's the use of a clothespin that's easy.

Comment: Imagine I need to process some photos, I resize them one by one, and then one of friends tell me a tip, which is, use a website to resize them in a batch; another  friend give me another tip, a snippet programming code. Obviously, the former tip is much easier than the latter, right?

Comment: No, we'd say, "it's an easier way to do something", not, "an easier tip".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How about the other 2, method and approach? I guess "The issue is that a tip" suggest that it is idiomatic to say "easy method" and "easy approach", right?